# How to enumerate all property names and entire values of a powershell command output?

Tags: powershell

Specifically I'm trying to take the output of `Get-OwaMailboxPolicy` and I want to add it to an array the same way it prints to screen (and expand some of the values completely that are truncated with a `...` ) so I can manipulate the data from there.

I've done this a thousand times with other commands, I'm not sure why this one is giving me such a hard time?

This should be the same issue whether in the cloud or on prem.

```
get-owamailboxpolicy
```

Comment: Any chance on closing this loop and accepting the below answer?

Answer (score 1):

### Enumerate all PowerShell output property values

It appears that you can simply set `$FormatEnumerationLimit =-1` and then when you run the command the output property values will no longer be truncated with the `...` ellipses. This `-1` value sets it to enumerate an unlimited number of items in the display output of the PowerShell command.

### PowerShell Script (Remove the property value truncation)

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit =-1;
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy;
```

**Before Output Sample**

```
AllowedFileTypes                                    : {.rpmsg, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb...}
AllowedMimeTypes                                    : {image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/bmp}
ForceSaveFileTypes                                  : {.vsmacros, .ps2xml, .ps1xml, .mshxml...}
ForceSaveMimeTypes                                  : {Application/x-shockwave-flash, Application/octet-stream, Application/futuresplash, Application/x-director}
BlockedFileTypes                                    : {.vsmacros, .msh2xml, .msh1xml, .ps2xml...}
BlockedMimeTypes                                    : {application/x-javascript, application/javascript, application/msaccess, x-internet-signup...}
```

**After Output Sample**

```
AllowedFileTypes                                    : {.rpmsg, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb, .tiff, .pptx, .pptm, .ppsx, .ppsm, .docx, .docm, .zip, .xls, .wmv, .wma, .wav, .vsd, .txt, .tif, .rtf, .pub, .ppt, .png, .pdf, 
                                                      .one, .mp3, .jpg, .gif, .doc, .bmp, .avi}
AllowedMimeTypes                                    : {image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/bmp}
ForceSaveFileTypes                                  : {.vsmacros, .ps2xml, .ps1xml, .mshxml, .gadget, .psc2, .psc1, .aspx, .wsh, .wsf, .wsc, .vsw, .vst, .vss, .vbs, .vbe, .url, .tmp, .swf, .spl, .shs, .shb, .sct, 
                                                      .scr, .scf, .reg, .pst, .ps2, .ps1, .prg, .prf, .plg, .pif, .pcd, .ops, .mst, .msp, .msi, .msh, .msc, .mdz, .mdw, .mdt, .mde, .mdb, .mda, .maw, .mav, .mau, 
                                                      .mat, .mas, .mar, .maq, .mam, .mag, .maf, .mad, .lnk, .ksh, .jse, .its, .isp, .ins, .inf, .hta, .hlp, .fxp, .exe, .dir, .dcr, .csh, .crt, .cpl, .com, .cmd, 
                                                      .chm, .cer, .bat, .bas, .asx, .asp, .app, .adp, .ade, .ws, .vb, .js}
ForceSaveMimeTypes                                  : {Application/x-shockwave-flash, Application/octet-stream, Application/futuresplash, Application/x-director}
BlockedFileTypes                                    : {.vsmacros, .msh2xml, .msh1xml, .ps2xml, .ps1xml, .mshxml, .gadget, .mhtml, .psc2, .psc1, .msh2, .msh1, .aspx, .xml, .wsh, .wsf, .wsc, .vsw, .vst, .vss, .vbs, 
                                                      .vbp, .vbe, .url, .tmp, .shs, .shb, .sct, .scr, .scf, .reg, .pst, .ps2, .ps1, .prg, .prf, .plg, .pif, .pcd, .osd, .ops, .mst, .msp, .msi, .msh, .msc, .mht, 
                                                      .mdz, .mdw, .mdt, .mde, .mdb, .mda, .maw, .mav, .mau, .mat, .mas, .mar, .maq, .mam, .mag, .maf, .mad, .lnk, .ksh, .jse, .its, .isp, .ins, .inf, .htc, .hta, 
                                                      .hpj, .hlp, .fxp, .exe, .der, .csh, .crt, .cpl, .com, .cnt, .cmd, .chm, .cer, .bat, .bas, .asx, .asp, .app, .adp, .ade, .ws, .vb, .js}
BlockedMimeTypes                                    : {application/x-javascript, application/javascript, application/msaccess, x-internet-signup, text/javascript, application/xml, application/prg, application/hta, 
                                                      text/scriplet, text/xml}
```

---

### PowerShell Script (Property `name:value` paired array)

```
Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | %{$_.PSObject.Members | ?{$_.MemberType -eq "Property"} | %{"$($_.Name): $($_.Value)"}}
```

**Sample Output**

```
AllowedFileTypes: .rpmsg .xlsx .xlsm .xlsb .tiff .pptx .pptm .ppsx .ppsm .docx .docm .zip .xls .wmv .wma .wav .vsd .txt .tif .rtf .pub .ppt .png .pdf .one .mp3 .jpg .gif .doc .bmp .avi
AllowedMimeTypes: image/jpeg image/png image/gif image/bmp
BlockedFileTypes: .vsmacros .msh2xml .msh1xml .ps2xml .ps1xml .mshxml .gadget .mhtml .psc2 .psc1 .msh2 .msh1 .aspx .xml .wsh .wsf .wsc .vsw .vst .vss .vbs .vbp .vbe .url .tmp .shs .shb .sct .scr .scf .reg .pst .ps2 
.ps1 .prg .prf .plg .pif .pcd .osd .ops .mst .msp .msi .msh .msc .mht .mdz .mdw .mdt .mde .mdb .mda .maw .mav .mau .mat .mas .mar .maq .mam .mag .maf .mad .lnk .ksh .jse .its .isp .ins .inf .htc .hta .hpj .hlp .fxp 
.exe .der .csh .crt .cpl .com .cnt .cmd .chm .cer .bat .bas .asx .asp .app .adp .ade .ws .vb .js
BlockedMimeTypes: application/x-javascript application/javascript application/msaccess x-internet-signup text/javascript application/xml application/prg application/hta text/scriplet text/xml
```

---

### Further Resources

- [About Preference Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6)

  - [$FormatEnumerationLimit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6#formatenumerationlimit)

    > Determines how many enumerated items are included in a display. This variable does not affect the underlying objects; just the display. When the value of `$FormatEnumerationLimit` is less than the number of enumerated items, PowerShell adds an ellipsis (`...`) to indicate items not shown.
    >
    > Valid values: Integers (Int32)
    >
    > Default value: 4
- [PSObject Constructors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.-ctor?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_PSObject__ctor_System_Object_)

Comment: That's an interesting tidbit, I didn't know that! What about putting the output into a parseable format or variable?

Comment: @Bbb I usually do that with something like `$var = Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | %{$_.AllowedFileTypes}` for example where within the loop you specify the property name explicitly. There are probably a few ways to do that, but I think you will have to be property name explicit for whatever values within that property you want to parse.

Comment: Hi, your solution works if you know the property name, what about if I don't know "AllowedFileTypes" is a property and instead I want to get all properties and values and put them in an array the way they are shown on screen?
`name      : value`

Comment: This worked to enumerate everything
$valz2 = Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Select -First 1 | foreach { $obj = $_; $_ | Get-Member -Type Property | where { $_.Name -notmatch "^_" } | foreach { "$($_.Name): $($obj.$($_.Name))" } }

Comment: Hi @Bbb .... Great, I see what you are saying more clearly now. I added a variation of this logic to the answer for completeness sake. Let me know if there's anything further. Glad to help you get a solution regardless that works for your needs